# How can I solve this equation in $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

$x^{2}+16x+55=3^{y^{2}-2y}$
Could you tell me how to solve this equation, please?
I tried to draw the graphic of the functions but I didn't see how to solve it.

Comment: Complete the square $(x+8)^2-9=3^{(y-1)^2-1}$. In new variables $a=x+8,b=y-1$ the equation becomes $a^2-9=3^{b^2-1}$. For $b=\pm1$ you get the equation $a^2=10$, which has no integer solutions. For other values of $b$ you get that $a^2=3^{b^2-1}+9$ must be multiple of $3$. Therefore, $a$ is multiple of $3$. Substitute $a=3k$. Then the equation becomes $k^2=3^{b^2-3}+1$, or $(k+1)(k-1)=3^{b^2-3}$. So, both $k+1$ and $k-1$ must be powers of $3$. But $(k+1)-(k-1)=2$, so the gcd of $k+1$ and $k-1$ must be either $1$ or $2$. It cannot be $3$. So, one of $k+1$ and $k-1$ must be $1$.

Comment: Note:  $x^2+16x+55=(x+5)(x+11)$

Comment: Thank you, MoonLightSyzgy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factoring gives $(x+5)(x+11)=3^{y^2-2y}$,
hence
\begin{align}
&x+5=3^u&
&x+11=3^v
\end{align}
for some $u,v$ with $0\leq u<v$.
Then
\begin{align}
6
&=(x+11)-(x+5)\\
&=3^u(3^{v-u}-1)
\end{align}
from which $u=1$ and $v-u=1$, hence $v=2$.
Consequently, $x=-2$ and $y^2-2y=3$ from which $y=3$ or $y=-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$3^{y^2-2y}=(x+11)(x+5)$$

As the left side is divisible by $3$ for $y^2-2y>1\iff(y-1)^2>2\implies y\ge3$ as $y$ is an integer

and as $x+11-(x+5)=6$

Either both or none is divisible by $3$

$$3^{y^2-2y-2}=\dfrac{x+11}3\cdot\dfrac{x+5}3$$

As exactly one of the multiplicands can be divisible by $3,$ the other must be $\pm1$

Check for $y\le2$ separately